# Entity Framework with TSQL's EncryptByPassPhrase

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t-sql

Apparently [TSQL has an "EncryptByPassPhrase"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/encryptbypassphrase-transact-sql) function to encrypt some data. In this [example](https://forums.asp.net/t/1645297.aspx?Problem%20to%20store%20encrypted%20data%20in%20database%20using%20asp%20net) I found, they use this code:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO  login_details(uid,username,password) VALUES(@uid,@username,EncryptByPassPhrase('12',@password))";
```

Is there any way to pass the `EncryptByPassPhrase` with all of its parameters into whatever EF does to add a record so that the DB uses this function? I tried with the only result being whatever I wrote concatenated as a string.

Comment: Strongly consider storing password hashes, not encrypted passwords. Encrypting all passwords in your database using the same passphrase for all of them offers far less added security than irreversibly hashing them.

Comment: Of course, yes, but it doesn't have to be a password necessarily - it's just a situation where the SQL portion of the insert procedure has EncryptByPassPhrase in it. Maybe for data other than password. Yet, how can it be possible for someone to obtain the pass phrase? Well, it could be an inside-job I suppose.

Comment: For starters, `12` is a horribly insecure passphrase. :-P Furthermore, anyone who can snoop on the SQL statements constructed by the application has access (like a hacker who successfully exploits an SQL injection issue or a vulnerability in the web server). It's also easy for people to get careless with the passphrase, especially if it's reused for other columns/tables/databases, so that it eventually leaks out in plaintext somewhere. The passwords of *all* your users can be decrypted instantly if that single passphrase ever gets out somewhere. This is not true for salted hashes.

Comment: Okay, I see all you mean. So now my question is, why do they still have EncryptByPassPhrase, and is there a situation where you'd not want some of the data be salt-hashed but rather encrypted? Such as, non-password data.

Comment: I'm not saying `ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE` is useless, it's just not as secure as solutions that don't require passing a key in plaintext. Alternatives include `ENCRYPTBYKEY` (unlike passphrases, you can restrict access to keys by accounts) and client-side encryption (including encrypting/decrypting explicitly in code and [Always Encrypted](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine)). `ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE` is certainly easy to use and can be "secure enough", depending on the attacker profile.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap them in stored procedures, which you can then import into your EF Model, to call from your .NET code.

Comment: I am going to read this link (http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/stored-procedure-in-entity-framework.aspx) , thank you.